# How can I set the coordinates of a picture in XML, Java

Tags: java, xml

Hello I am trying to make an app with java and XML and I want to have a picture in a specific location on the page. How would I do this?
I tried:

```
ImageView sprite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sprite);
sprite.setX(0);
sprite.setY(500);
```

and I got an error at `sprite.setX(0);` and `sprite.setY(500);`
setX or setY does not exist...

Comment: I don't see how XML is involved in this.

Comment: The ImageView part is the layout in XML... And I am making the app with java and xml

Comment: I mean I don't see how your question relates to XML - as far as I can tell you're just having issues with the `ImageView` class, is that right?

Comment: Yes I am using XML to make the app and I would like to know how to move the ImageView class to a different area on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all, I do not see any relationship with XML, you should post all your code so we can analyze it and find what that error produces
>   It's strange that there are no setX and setY methods in your ImageView control, maybe you're trying to call setX and setY in the wrong place

But assuming no, you can try the following:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams param = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height, int x, int y)

sprite.setLayoutParams(param);
```

where

```
int X = 0;
int Y = 500;
YourLayout.LayoutParams param = new YourLayout.LayoutParams(sprite.getMeasuredWidth(), sprite.getMeasuredHeight(), X, Y);
sprite.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Also

Suppose you want a ImageView of size 80x90 on your screen at postion 90x60

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

ImageView sprite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sprite);

//Where 80 is the width and 90 the height
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 90);

// Setting position of our ImageView
//you can use the margins of the layout
layoutParams.leftMargin = 80;
layoutParams.topMargin = 90;
//layoutParams.rightMargin = 80; //Example
//layoutParams.bottomMargin = 90; //Example


relativeLayout.addView(imageView, layoutParams);
```

In any case, I recommend you post your complete code so we can help you

Comment: @FlamingBurrito15 For nothing, I'm glad I helped you, in that case, I recommend that you mark my post as accepted, so that other readers know that this was the correct answer